# HTTPS connections duplicated

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Additional, unexpected HTTPS connections are being made to GCE servers.

This started 2nd October and is affecting europe-west1-b and us-central1-b.

We have the same codebase running on servers in Amazon EC2 that are not affected.

Is anyone else seeing issues with HTTPS traffic to GCE?

**UPDATE: Clarification of duplicated connections:**

A single HTTPS request from a web browser for example

`GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1`

Results in 5 HTTPS connections opened, no http request is send and then they are closed (before timeout period).

Then a final connection is opened and the request is sent as it should.

**Note:**
This usually would go undetected. However we only allow 10 SSL connections from a single IP in the space of 1 second (velocity restriction).

I have temporarily increased this to 20 and everything is working OK.

What I don't understand is why this would suddenly start happening and only on GCE servers.

I will update this again when I have looked into the raw SSL traffic.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "duplicated"?

Comment: This is still a problem. I would like to understand why this occurs. It only happens on Google Compute Engine.